# Javascript issue on Report Viewer Control

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We recently upgraded to SQL 2012 which uses SSRS 2008.

On "certain" IE10 browsers we are getting a javascript issue.

Basically trying to resize images.

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'PollResizeImages'
```

Anyone come across this.

Tried few IE settings as it does not seem to be server related. e.g. Clear browser settings, enable a few security settings...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of the Report Viewer do you have installed on the server? Maybe try this version --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode?

Comment: Tried that with the 2012 clr types but does not seemed to have worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes tried compatibility mode - currently running IE 10 Compat mode